# Can you disable Today's Date in the Today View in Yosemite Notification Center?

Tags: macos, notifications

While it's possible to remove the Today Summary from the view you cannot remove the date. It's superfluous while using a calendar app such as Fantastical.  Any way to tweak this?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a [thread on Macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/removing-todays-date-in-today-notification-center-view.1816663/) that perhaps might be a good starting point?

Comment: I was able to modify the com.apple.nc.today.date value in com.apple.notificationcenterui plist, as mentioned in the link above. It doesn't affect the notification centre, though, even if you disable it while modifying the plist.